# Always toggle edit mode off

Tags: edit-mode

This one is simple. My operator acts up if the current object is in edit mode. So I would like to make sure to untoggle edit mode if it is the case. The code below works:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

But it crashes if no object is active. So something like this:

```
if not context.active_object:
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Except that this doesn't work, and maybe there is a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: `if bpy.context.active_object is not None:` ?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not a python shark... that would be a cool animal, though...